# Span /home on multiple partitions

Tags: filesystems, partition, fstab

I am going for installing Gentoo for the second time. I read that multiple swap partitions can be created and their entries in `/etc/fstab` can be prioritised with `pri` mount option. Just wanted to ask whether that can be done with `/home` too. Like
`/dev/sda1 /home ext4 defaults,pri=1 0 2` and `/dev/sda2 /home ext4 defaults,pri=2 0 2`. Thanks!

Comment: Nah, it won't work this way.

You could use https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs (and similar), LVM or ZFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not that way.

But there are other ways. Here are a few methods, they all do slightly different things.

- Union file systems: create a layered file-system. A read-only as the base, then another overlay that is writable, and stored only the changes.
- LVM, ZFS (and some other file systems): allow file-systems to span multiple partitions / disks.
- Raid: allow file-systems to span multiple partitions / disks. (but for other reasons)
- Symbolic linking: Allow you to make a file/sub-directory be in a different place.
- Mount points in `/home`: Allow you to make a file/sub-directory be in a different place.